# Can a group homeomorphism $G\to Y$ have $Y\subsetneq G$?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G,\cdot,d$ be a group in a metric space

Let $\phi:G\to Y$ be an injective group isomorphism such that $Y\subsetneq G$ but satisfying $\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi^n(G)=G$.  Here $\subsetneq$ indicates proper subset (rather than subgroup) and $n$ indicates composition.

This looks for all the world like a homeomorphism to me, but it's unclear to me whether having an inverse means a homeomorphism must be onto.

Can a homeomorphism not have $Y\subsetneq G$?

Comment: Question title does not match question, words are used randomly and without understanding their definition (both a a "homeomorphism" and an "isomorphism" are onto by definition; how is a map $\phi: G \rightarrow Y$ a group isomorphism if $Y$ is not a group). -1

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I appreciate you're pissed off with me but it can't have been than unclear given you managed to answer the question in your comment.

Comment: What do you mean by $\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi^n(G)=G$? (Like union, or some other type of limit?) If $\phi(G)\subseteq Y$ then $\phi^n(G)\subseteq Y$ for all $n$, cannot think of a suitable interpretation of $\lim$ that would make subsets of $Y$ have $\lim$ equal to $G$. Of course, something like $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ with $m\mapsto2m$, so $Y=2\Bbb Z$ (just a simple example to see what might happen), but then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi^n(\Bbb Z)=\varnothing$, at least set-theoretically (limit is same as intersection in this case, $\cap_n2^n\Bbb Z$ ).

Comment: @Mirko yes, I just mean the infinite limit surjects even though the function itself doesn't. Turns out I just wrote up the example in more detail: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448380/ please do let me know if I did anything wrong as I am constantly stretching myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\phi[G]$ is a subgroup of $Y$ (just group theory) (which is itself a proper subgroup of $G$, if I understand you correctly). So $\phi^n[G]$ is just going to be  only smaller, as $\phi^2[G]=\phi[\phi[G]]\subseteq \phi[G]$ and so on by induction. So the supposed limit (however that limit is defined, their intersection is the only reasonable guess as we have a decreasing family of subgroups of $Y$) can only itself be some subgroup of $Y$ and never $G$. So the question is moot, IMO.

Comment: Thank-you for this. Does this result depend upon the group axioms over and above a monoid?  I just wrote up the example here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448380/ which illustrates the function that itself does not surject, while its infinite limit does.  It is a monoid quotient rather than a group, although I tentatively thought I might also be able to impose a group structure upon it by changing the operations.